# Extract text and (hlStart and hlEnd) tags from simple html

Tags: python, r, xml-parsing, html-parsing, tei

I have a following part of html/xml file:

```
<p><hlstart ana="#ann224094"></<hlstart>Przed<hlend ana="#ann224094"></hlend> <hlstart ana="#ann224160"></hlstart>nami <hlend ana="#ann224160"></hlend>jeszcze trzy <hlstart ana="#ann224159"></hlstart>dni,<hlend ana="#ann224159"></hlend></p>
```

I'd like to extract text and tags to arrange them in the table like:

```
text, nonana
text, ana
```

where ana means tag such as #ann224094 from

```
<hlstart ana="#ann224094"></<hlstart>Przed<hlend ana="#ann224094"></hlend>
```

and nonana means text has no ana tag.

```
przed, #ann224094
nami, #ann224160
jeszcze trzy, nonana
```

I've tried bs4 and htmlparser with other parts of my xml data, but I don't understand that part. I can export whole text, all strings with .text method, but I need to know which words have ana tags. Furthermore, all words with ana tags have specific labels later in my files.

Answer (score 2):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = '''<p><hlstart ana="#ann224094"></hlstart>Przed<hlend ana="#ann224094"></hlend> <hlstart ana="#ann224160"></hlstart>nami <hlend ana="#ann224160"></hlend>jeszcze trzy <hlstart ana="#ann224159"></hlstart>dni,<hlend ana="#ann224159"></hlend></p>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

out = []
for t in soup.find_all(text=True):
    if t.strip() == '':
        continue

    prev = t.find_previous_sibling()
    if prev.name == 'hlstart':
        out.append( (t, prev['ana']) )
    else:
        out.append( (t, 'noana') )

# print it to screen:
from pprint import pprint
pprint(out)
```

Prints:

```
[('Przed', '#ann224094'),
 ('nami ', '#ann224160'),
 ('jeszcze trzy ', 'noana'),
 ('dni,', '#ann224159')]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another method, using lxml:

```
    ana = """your html above"""
    import lxml.html as lh

    doc = lh.fromstring(ana)
    targets = doc.xpath('//hlstart[@ana]')
    nont = doc.xpath('//*[name() != "hlstart"]')

    for target in targets:
        if target.tail is not None:
            print(target.attrib['ana'],target.tail.strip())

    for n in nont:
        if n.tail is not None and len(n.tail.strip())>0:
           print('noanna ',n.tail.strip())
```

Output:

```
#ann224094 Przed
#ann224160 nami
#ann224159 dni,
noanna  jeszcze trzy
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method, using SimplifiedDoc :)

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc,utils
html = '''
<p>
<hlstart ana="#ann224094"></hlstart>Przed<hlend ana="#ann224094"></hlend> 
<hlstart ana="#ann224160"></hlstart>nami <hlend ana="#ann224160"></hlend>
jeszcze trzy 
<hlstart ana="#ann224159"></hlstart>dni,<hlend ana="#ann224159"></hlend></p>'''

doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
for h in doc.p.hlstarts:
    text = h.nextText()
    if text: print(h.ana,text)
for h in doc.p.hlends:
    text = h.nextText()
    if text: print('noana',text)
```

Result:

```
#ann224094 Przed
#ann224160 nami
#ann224159 dni,
noana jeszcze trzy
```